# Странная ошибка в коде

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, выдает ошибку в строке 3

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $header = [];
    protected $data = [];
    protected $footer = [];
    protected $user = false;
```

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: уже разобрался, версия php, извините что не указал саму ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите какую ошибку пишет?
Возможно у Вас на сервере используется версия php 5.3 или ниже, тогда массивы нужно объявлять так

```
protected $header = array();
protected $data = array();
protected $footer = array();
```

Но все же лучше перейти на более новую версию php